# Why are my C++ and Fortran programs not running on Plato IDE downloaded from Silverfrost?

Tags: c++, ide, runtime-error, plato

I am using Plato IDE from Silverfrost FTN95 to run programs on Fortran as well as C++. But for the last 2-3 months, I was busy and could not use them. So, yesterday when I opened the IDE and viewed some earlier written programs, I saw that the programs were not running properly.

The compiler was working and each time, the compilation was completed with no errors.
[image]

The executable was also built successfully but it just showed the following:[image]

Also, on clicking "Run to Cursor" on any line of the program, it mentioned the following error.
[image]

What is wrong? And how do I make things work right? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: @CodyGray But it used to run correctly with output 3 months ago. Also every program that I have written till date cannot be run here any more. Although the same programs can be run on online IDE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not realise what was wrong, in any way possible. So I uninstalled it and then performed re-installation. Things are working so fine now.

Comment: You collapsed the wave function